# Can you extend a type/record to implement the str function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a type `Book` defined with `defrecord`, and a function to convert it into a string:

```clj
(defrecord Book [title author])
(defn book->string [book] (str (:title book) " by " (:author book))) 

(book->string (->Book "Foo" "Bar"))  ;; "Foo by Bar"
```

Is it possible to extend the record so that I can call `(str (->Book "Foo" "Bar"))` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to extend anything, just overwrite `toString` method:

```
(defrecord Book [title author]
  Object
  (toString [_] (str title " by " author)))
```

Test:

```
(str (->Book "Foo" "Bar"))
=> "Foo by Bar"
```

Comment: But also like, consider not doing it at all. `toString` is for debugging, and records already have a great debugging string representation. If you want to present the object to a user, use a different function than `str`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Martin and a great point you raised ammaloy! I came from the Python world and thus was a bit more accustomed to overwriting the default `str()` function. Is it the case that in Clojure, if for example you were to use a library, you would expect `(library/string record)` instead of `(str record)` ?